# Ember App Kit - Which way to register Handlebars Helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-app-kit

Over at the [Ember App Kit website](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/) one can see two methods to create `Handlebars` helper methods where the **first** one (can be seen [here](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/using-modules.html)) uses the following steps:

- `export default` a function which takes two arguments and dasherize
  the file name so that it could be found by the `ember-jj-abrams`
  resolver.
- `import` the function/file in `app.js` and call `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` to register the helper
  function.

The **second** one (could be seen [here](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/naming-conventions.html)) uses a different way, where you `export default` the whole function wrapped in the `Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper` function which is documented to be

> ...(mostly) private helper function to registerBoundHelper. Takes the
>   provided Handlebars helper function fn and returns it in wrapped bound
>   helper form.
>
> The main use case for using this outside of registerBoundHelper is for
>   registering helpers on the container...

Find it at the Ember Documentation [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_makeBoundHelper).

So, as I interpret the documentation, if I use the **second** method I would have to register the helper in the container within an `Ember.initializer` in `app.js`, am I right? Is there any difference so that one would prefer one over the other?